# Fluentd not parsing multiline logs

Tags: fluentd

I am trying to parse syslog multiline input in Fluentd . The sample log looks like this -

```
"737 <14>1 2018-04-27T17:32:55.401896+00:00 CMB.V02G-dev-digital-billing.fluenddemoservice 598c519b-a092-431a-a8bb-a834f259b0d2 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] - - 2018-04-27 17:32:55.401  INFO 14 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.v.f.f.controller.DemoController        : {\"application\":\"myFios\",\"logType\":\"OperationalMetrics\",\"uniqueId\":\"vzid\",\"sessionId\":\"1221354410\",\"transactionId\":\"qwedfg45678789\",\"deviceId\":\"ajkrtyghyu\",\"api\":\"API\",\"status\":\"S\",\"failureMessage\":\"\",\"failureCode\":\"\",\"responseTime\":\"10\",\"osType\":\"android\",\"osVersion\":\"1.1\",\"deviceModel\":\"Chrome\",\"appVersion\":\"5.4.3.2\",\"createDate\":\"2018-04-17 14:43:13.046\",\"instance\":\"1\",\"dataCenter\":\"Tampa\",\"customerType\":\"C\",\"apiGroup\":\"\",\"apiBackend\":\"SSP\",\"apiVersion\":\"v2\",\"data\":\"{\\\"key\\\":\\\"value\\\"}\"}"
```

My end goal is to extract  the JSON from this log.
I used an online regex editor to buld the regex and I am able to achieve this using this regex

{\"application(.*)\"}

But Fluend does not undeerstand this regex. it complains that regex is not valid. Please help me what should I do to  make sure Fluend understands the (?s) option.
Below is my FLuend configuration

```
 @type tcp
  tag cf.app # required
  <parse>
    @type regexp
   expression /{\\"application(.*)\"}/
   multiline true
  </parse>
  port 5140   # optional. 5170 by default
  bind 0.0.0.0 # optional. 0.0.0.0 by default
```

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: The braces (`{` and `}`) have special meaning in regular expressions. You probably have to escape them as `\{` and `\}` respectively.

Comment: It is not working. I have escaped  the curly braces. I dont want to escape the ( and ) because I want to enforce multiline parsing. It perfectly works in the regex editor but does not work in Fluentd.

Comment: Looks like (?s) is not supported by Ruby.

Comment: I have removed the (?s) still it is not working in Fluend. It is working fine in regex editor.